# Is it possible to IMPORTDATA in Google Sheets into one specific cell with line breaks rather than into new columns?

Tags: regex, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

For example, I'm trying to do a `REGEXEXTRACT` from data on an imported page, but it's delimiting and going into hundreds of columns.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTDATA("https://url.js"),"id.*")
```

Answer (score 1):

when using `IMPORTDATA` it's handy to wrap it into `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN`

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA("https://url.js"), 500, 1), "id.*")
```

Comment: Thanks, this shows me the columns, but is missing a lot of data. When I increment the 500,1 to 500,2 it shows me data that's hidden. It's just a .js file that I'm trying to import and get data from, so wondering if it can be all added to one cell as a block.

Comment: depends what you mean under: "all added to one cell as a block"... try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(REGEXEXTRACT(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA("https://url.js"), 500, 1), "id.*")),,999^99)),,999^99))`

Comment: Hm, that doesn't quite work. 

I'm trying to get the values for `"embed_url"`, `"app_id"` and `"url_name"`, which I'm _hoping_ I should be able to do with a combination of `IMPORTDATA`, `REGEXEXTRACT`?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k5To0nKdDVMvGNTw3RVPBWdis8SF04yA-1ILCbpwAvI/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

Use [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?sjid=15958558852089006910-NC):

> Combines the text from multiple strings and/or arrays, with a specifiable delimiter separating the different texts.

Example:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(
TEXTJOIN(",", FALSE, IMPORTDATA("https://url.js")),
"id.*")
```

The first argument to `TEXTJOIN` is a delimiter. A comma probably caused Google Sheets to split the result into columns, so we will add the comma back in.

The second argument to `TEXTJOIN` is whether to ignore empty cells. I don't think it matters for this.

It looks this is not a perfect solution, for example quotation marks at the beginning of a column get removed.